# What movie had a John Stamos-like character dreaming on a medical spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, spaceship, dreams

I saw this movie about 6 or 7 years ago, it was definitely older than that though.

It takes place on a medical transport spaceship that crash lands on an alien world while the ship was on its way to deliver vaccines to another planet. The main character is male and white and for some reason I remember him looking like John Stamos from Full House. He has a daughter on that planet who is in need of the vaccine.

The ship crashes and they are stuck on the surface of this gassy alien world when the local wildlife starts to attack. The aliens are a parasite creature that attaches to a human and injects them with a dream serum that makes them dream and babble on about their dreams, in a coma like state. During the first attack the lead character is grazed by one of the terrors and begins going through bouts of dream like state.

Herein lies the main dilemma. On one side of the dream, his ship was found and rescued and they delivered the medicine and he and his wife and child live happily together, but when he goes to sleep he enters a dream where he is back on the ship, having never been rescued. In this consciousness his world tries to convince him that it's just PTSD from the ordeal. While in the other side he is still on the ship having never been rescued and the (two?) crew members left try to convince him that the former "happy" life is the dream, and they still need to escape.

He ultimately decides to go with the second world and launches an escape pod abandoning his comrades and soaring into space with the medicine while saying "I made it, I did it, I saved her"

> The camera pans out and it is shown that he has always been dreaming and that everyone on board the ship is also infected just laying around murmuring the dream like state. And that the ship was lost and not recovered.

Does anyone happen to know the name of this film?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have an excelent start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Made me wonder what a `John Stamos-like character` was. XD (Might want to edit the title to `John Stamos-looking actor` or `movie with an actor resembling John Stamos`)

Comment: The actor was Eric McCormack (Will from Will & Grace).

Comment: Yeah, someone edited the title block a bit, but I am so glad that someone found it, I was going nuts trying to hunt it down

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an *Outer Limits* episode, [Tempests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempests_(The_Outer_Limits)). The vaccine, parasites, venom-induced hallucinations and the dark ending all match.

> Commander Virgil is desperately attempting to deliver a serum to his home colony, which is being devastated by a virus, Ellycia C. His wife and young son are there. After his ship crashes into a gas giant, he finds himself shifting between two realities: an ideal one, and one in crisis.
>
> In the "bad" reality, the crash site turns out to be the interior of a living being; while conducting repairs, Virgil is bitten by a spider-like creature and its venom causes him to hallucinate. In the "good" reality, the crew were rescued and delivered the serum; Virgil is living happily with his family but is in treatment for Ellycia C., which is causing him to hallucinate. In each reality, he perceives the other reality as a hallucination, and he is warned he could die if he does not struggle against the other, "false" reality.
>
> Virgil reasons that his family are already safe if the "good" reality is true, but they still need the serum if the "bad" reality is true; so he embraces the "bad" reality to ensure their survival. He heads for the colony in an escape pod and makes contact with his wife, believing he is on track to save both the crew and the colony. However, both realities are false; Virgil and the entire crew are unconscious and being fed on by the alien spiders.

Comment: Might want to expand to include the title of the episode and a description just a little bit.